# Always open specific domains in a different browser from Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, domain

I would like to force specific domains (say facebook or twitter) to always open in Chrome instead of Firefox which is my default browser.

There is an extension called "Open With" which can be used to manually reopen a page on another browser. Is there any way to automatically force this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

I use an addon called [IE view](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/35/) that does this. It allows you to use any browser you want, and only uses IE if you don't tell it to use something else.

As you can see I have told it to use Chrome
[image: IE view options screen]

Comment: This is interesting. I might eventually use this. I did not mention this in the question to keep it simple, What I actually want to attempt is to have different domains open in different browsers. So one browser for social networking sites, one browser for emails and one sanitized browser for bank accounts. If the email browser is default, I want it to force the social n/w links to open in the social n/w browser (I hope you get what I was trying to say)