# Is there a way to redirect certain URLs to specific web browsers in Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, browser, url, internet-filter

I'm using Chrome as my default browser in Ubuntu 12.10. I need to use Firefox for business purposes (certain websites pertaining to my work only work with Firefox). Is there a way to force Ubuntu to use Firefox for certain types of URLs (maybe as defined by a regular expression) while maintaining Chrome as my default browser for all my other tasks? Perhaps as a shell script running in the background? I'd like this to work system-wide, covering links from Chrome itself as well as PDFs/ODTs, etc.

I have searched for solutions, but I couldn't find anything besides OpenWith, a Firefox extension which adds a button to open certain links in other browsers which would again require me to open Firefox beforehand, which does not help me at all.

Does anyone have any ideas? Something like [Choosy](http://www.choosyosx.com/) for Linux?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/198179/always-open-specific-domains-in-a-different-browser-from-firefox?rq=1

Comment: Well I'm using Linux so it's not that relevant...

Answer (score 14):

The executable in Linux that opens a resource with your "favorite" program is called `xdg-open`. It is somewhat complicated, but you can add additional rules using `xdg-mime install`. However, I don't know if you can even do this for something like a specific URL.

This becomes further complicated in that specific desktop environments use different executables and methods for opening their default programs. For instance KDE has `kde-open`, but not every KDE application seems to use this.

Regardless, I got this partially working just using a shell script and a list of domains/URLs in a file. You can tweak it to your liking.

**Note:** You *may* need to repeat this process for other executables depending on your desktop environment. For example, Gnome has `gvfs-open`, KDE has `kde-open`, and XFCE has `exo-open`. (Even then, it might not work for every application.)

**Note:** The shell script is dependent on `pcregrep` being installed on your system.

1. Find the `xdg-open` executable

   ```
   which xdg-open
   ```
2. Create a new directory in your home folder

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
   ```
3. Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file

   *~/.bashrc*

   ```
   export PATH="${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}"
   ```
4. Create the shell script in the newly created folder. (Be sure to edit the top four variables so they are correct for your system!)

   *~/.local/bin/xdg-open*

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   DOMAIN_LIST_FILE=~/'domains.txt'
   OTHER_BROWSER='/path/to/other-browser' # For instance /usr/bin/firefox
   BROWSER_OPTIONS='' # Optional, for command line options passed to browser
   XDG_OPEN='/path/to/xdg-open'

   if echo "$1" | pcregrep -q '^https?://'; then
       matching=0
       while read domain; do
           if echo "$1" | pcregrep -q "^https?://${domain}"; then
               matching=1
               break
           fi
       done < "$DOMAIN_LIST_FILE"

       if [[ $matching -eq 1 ]]; then
           "$OTHER_BROWSER" $BROWSER_OPTIONS ${*}
           exit 0
       fi
   fi

   "$XDG_OPEN" ${*}
   ```
5. Create the list of domains in your home folder

   *~/domains.txt*

   ```
   stackexchange.com
   stackoverflow.com
   superuser.com
   ```
6. Log out and log back in to have the settings take effect

Comment: change `pcregrep -q '^https?://'` to `grep -q '^http\?:\/\/'` if you don't have pcregrep (whatever that is :) )

Comment: Don't forget to `chmod +x ~/.local/bin/xdg-open` and use `grep -q '^https\?:\/\/'` (note the `s`) instead of `grep -q '^http\?:\/\/'`, as mentioned in [just above comment](https://superuser.com/questions/688063/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-certain-urls-to-specific-web-browsers-in-linux#comment1556354_688094).